# Is it possible to combine two mix'es in one file in Laravel Elixir?

Tags: javascript, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

So I have a lot of JS components in separated files and also have some components which are global for all. I want combine each file of component and join in with global ones. Something like this:

```
mix.scriptsIn('components/user/products', 'public/js/product.js').scripts([
        'components/global.js',
        'modules/underscore.js'
    ], 'public/js/product.js')
```

P.S.

I cant use Browserify as some of the code need to be in global scope.